# SyntaxError: unexpected EOF while parsing Библиотека yadisk

Tags: python

Сам код

```
import yadisk
y = yadisk.YaDisk(token="Тут мой токен")
y.upload("Tags.txt", "/Tags.txt")
```

Ошибка

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\User\Desktop\Heroku\yandex.py", line 1, in <module>
    import yadisk
  File "C:\Users\User\Desktop\Heroku\yadisk.py", line 43

    ^
SyntaxError: unexpected EOF while parsing
```

Пытался скачать библиотеку с гитхаба,или даже старые версии не работает все равно

Comment: Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.

Comment: В `Google Colab` нормально ставится через `pip install yadisk` и подключается `import yadisk` версия `yadisk-1.2.15`. У вас какая версия питона, может с ней `yadisk` несовместим?

Comment: У меня питон версии 3.8.6

Comment: А, стоп, у вас же локально лежит файл `yadisk.py`, вы в него смотрели, что там вообще? 43 строки это немного, покажите, что там, добавьте код к вопросу.

Comment: В этом коде почему-та нету на 43 строки нечего
Все я понял в чем была ошибка

Comment: Ну там сразу было написано в ошибке, что код в этом файле неожиданно обрывается.